# Proxy server not respond error in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, localhost, proxy-server

Whenever I open `localhost:8080`on my browser url-bar to open my Apache Tomcat's local host page then I found,

```
This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests.
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What process is listening to port `8080`?

Comment: Apache Tomcat Server

Comment: Tomcat does not include proxying capabilities, so that message is either coming from a component you installed, or Tomcat isn't actually listening on port `8080`.

Comment: But my port `8080` is free.

Comment: How I can solve this problem?

Comment: So... port `8080` is both free and running Apache Tomcat? How is that possible?